# Monitor class in Java

Tags: java

I want to know about `Monitor` class in Java.

What is it used for, where is it used?

Comment: Hey, if the provided answer answers your question you will want to select it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The [Monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/monitor/Monitor.html) class is an abstract class that is extended by some of the standard MBean classes defined in the `javax.management.monitoring` package.  It provides infrastructure for configuring the objects monitored/observed by an MBean, and for making those observations.

You normally wouldn't use the Monitor class directly unless you were implementing your own [`MonitorMBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/monitor/MonitorMBean.html) classes.

(Note this is "monitor" as in "observe what it going on inside a server" rather than "monitor" as in "concurrent programming primitive".)

Comment: Nice to see an actual explanation rather than copy/pasted API links.

Answer (score 0):

These links helps you

http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch2.html

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/management/monitor/package-tree.html

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/monitor/Monitor.html